# inheritance and roles

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, role

Let's use a quite plain example with `employees and company(-ies)`.

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    // bunch of its features
}

public sealed class SalesManager : Employee
{
}

public sealed class SEO : Employee
{
}
```

Employee can take different posts or play different roles. So using inheritance (maybe with factory patterns in addition) doesn't give such a flexibility for `concrete employee instance` to change its role.

What would you advice, unfortunately I haven't seen the kind of approaches yet. And I haven't met a book which lights up the problem.

### Edit

Thank you guys! In my edit I wanted to ask one more thing. Using `generic role` is it possible to transfer such a BLL to DAL. I have heard that generics are not supported in `Entity Framework`??

Thanks!

Comment: Don't fully understand -- do you mean you want employee instances to be polymorphic, able to become a different Type of employee at the instance-level?

Comment: As you have learned, inheritance is a poor choice to model Roles because an instance type is fixed upon creation.  To the no resources part of your question this is a commonly encountered scenario.  I usually try to attempt a design myself first, but among others you could consider Fowler's approach: http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accountability.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a has-a relationship

```
public class Employee 
{
    public Role EmployeeRole { get; set; }
}

public enum Role 
{
    SalesManager,
    SalesPerson
}
```

Or you can make `Role` a class to store additional information in addition to the name of their role.

```
public class Role
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal BaseSalary { get; set; }
}
```

---

To illustrate @Aasmund Eldhuset's comment:

```
public abstract class Role
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal BaseSalary { get; set; }

    public abstract void PerformRole();
}

public class SalesPerson : Role
{
    public void PerformRole()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. `Role` could also be an abstract class (with subclasses) such that you can build behaviour into the roles.

Comment: @Aasmund can't get the need? Where it is useful, please do illustrate?

Comment: @Kyle it is cool (your edit) and simple, using the approach salary is bound to `role` object, not `employee`! Thanks!

Comment: @helicera: Say that you have some complicated business rules about e.g. salaries. Then, the `Employee` method for calculating salary could have a big if/else that checks what kind of role the employee is in and performs decisions based on that. However, a somewhat prettier solution is to have an abstract method in `Role` that is overloaded in each subclass to performs the appropriate computation. Then, `Employee` can simply call this method without any if/else.

Comment: @Kyle @Aasmund Ok I get it, the trick there is in the `PerformRole` method. It behaves like salary calculator.

Answer (score 2):

Running with the idea of using a class, you can make it generic:

```
abstract class EmployeeRole { }
```

or

```
interface EmployeeRole { }
```

And have different types inherit from this abstraction:

```
class CEO : EmployeeRole { }

class SalesMgr : EmployeeRole { }

class Employee<T> where T : EmployeeRole
{

}
```

Then have a generic Factory implementation:

```
public Employee<T> MakeEmployee<T>() where T : EmployeeRole
{

}
```